# How to write query for left join

Tags: mysql

i have written left join query and i want the product_code column of left table should be updated by the product_code column of right table  by the condition of below query

```
update stock_details_mt as s  left join 
(select min(product_code),product_name,mrp,sales_rate from stock_details_mt  group by product_name,mrp,sales_rate having count(*)>1)as s2  set
 s.product_code=s2.product_code on s.product_name=s2.product_name where s.mrp=s2.mrp and s.sales_rate=s2.sales_rate ;
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have lost the plot between the join and set and I would be suspicious of the left join. Try this.

```
update stock_details_mt as s join 
(select min(product_code) product_code,product_name,mrp,sales_rate 
from stock_details_mt  
group by product_name,mrp,sales_rate 
having count(*)>1) as s2  
on s.product_name=s2.product_name and s.mrp=s2.mrp and s.sales_rate=s2.sales_rate 
set  s.product_code=s2.product_code 
where  1 = 1;
```

So given

```
drop table if exists stock_details_mt;

create table stock_details_mt
(product_code int, product_name varchar(10), mrp int, sales_rate int);

insert into stock_details_mt values
(2,'aaa',1,1),(1,'aaa',1,1),(10,'aaa',1,1),
(10,'bbb',1,1);
```

Result

```
+--------------+--------------+------+------------+
| product_code | product_name | mrp  | sales_rate |
+--------------+--------------+------+------------+
|            1 | aaa          |    1 |          1 |
|            1 | aaa          |    1 |          1 |
|            1 | aaa          |    1 |          1 |
|           10 | bbb          |    1 |          1 |
+--------------+--------------+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Manik if you are happy with the answer would you like to accept it.